# Identification through digital signature. How safe is it?

Tags: digital-signature, identity

Let's say I want to give some data to Bob. I have his public key. I tell him to generate a digital signature for text "{some_stuff: 1, nonce: 2}". After he does that and after I verify it's the right signature, I give him the data. I use a different nonce for each session. Is there anything I need to be aware of? Is it pretty secure?

Answer (score 1):

Digital signatures are used extensively for authentication in many secure protocols, such as SSL/TLS, SSH, etc.  Of course, this requires the verifiying party to have some way of knowing that the public key purported to belong to the autheticating party is true and correct.

The parts that are not clear from the description of your process are:  1) How does Bob authenticate you?, and 2) How is the data transferred from you to Bob securely?

Ideally, your protocol should have a way for the client and the server to mutually authenticate each other, and for the data be encrypted as it is sent through the network.  It's best if the encryption is done using `perfect forward secrecy` (PFS), so that if an eavesdropper on the network records the cyphertext passing through, he can not later decrypt the cyphertext even if one of the parties' private keys is later compromised.

For the sake of this question, assume that each party has a long-term key pair, and each party has some way of knowing that the public key purported to belong to the other party is true and correct.  Modern protocols (such as those mentioned above) accomplish all of the above using a method along the lines of the following:

1. Client generates an ephemeral key pair and sends ephemeral public key to server.
2. Server generates an ephemeral key pair and computes shared secret using server's ephemeral private key and client's ephemeral public key.  Server signs shared secret using server's long-term private key, and sends ephemeral public key and signature to client.
3. Client computes shared secret using client's ephemeral private key and server's ephemeral public key.  Client verifies server's signature on shared secret using server's long-term public key.  Client signs shared secret using client's long-term private key, and sends signature to server.
4. Server verifies client's signature on shared secret using client's long-term public key.

At this point, if all of the signatures have verified, the client has authenticated the server, the server has authenticated the client, and the client and server share a shared secret.  This shared secret can be used as an encryption key to a symmetric encryption algorithm (such as AES), so that the two parties can share information between each other securely.  At the end of the session, both parties discard the shared secret and the ephemeral keys to ensure PFS.

Answer (score 0):

You've described some parts of a secure channel protocol. But on its own, what you've described doesn't achieve much. You haven't stated what security property you expect, so it's impossible to say whether it's “secure”.

It's important to realize that this protocol does not ensure that only Bob can get the data. Suppose that both Bob and Eve want the data, and Alice is prepared to give the data to Bob and not to Eve. Bob performs your protocol: Alice sends him a nonce, Bob replies with the expected signature, and Alice sends the data to Bob. Eve eavesdrops when Alice sends the data to Bob, so she gets the data as well.

If you assume that Alice can't eavesdrop on the communication between Alice and Bob, then your protocol was useless: you could just have Alice send the data to Bob, the end.

Another thing you should be aware of is that this protocol is not “identification through digital signature”. Identification is rarely a useful security property because all identification tells you is “Bob is here”, it doesn't tell you “Bob sent this message”. “Bob sent this message” is authenticity, which is the textbook application of digital signatures. You included a nonce and a marker (“some_stuff”) in the data to be signed, which is good: it ties Bob's identity to the request that he's making, so when Alice receives a signed message from Bob, she knows not only that Bob is trying to communicate with her, but also what Bob wants from her. The problem with your protocol is that it doesn't allow Alice to do anything useful with the information that Bob wants this data.

If eavesdroppers are a concern, Alice needs to encrypt the data that she sends to Bob in such a way that only Bob (and possibly Alice herself) can decrypt it. There are two solutions for that. One is for Bob to publish an *encryption* public key instead of a signature public key. Alice encrypts the data with a single-use symmetric key, and encrypts this symmetric key with Bob's public key. She then sends Bob the encrypted data together with the encrypted symmetric key. This combination of encrypted data can be public if there are no privacy concerns (if you want to hide the fact that Alice is communicating with Bob, it's a different problem). The other solution is for Alice and Bob to establish a secure channel, which in the real world means TLS (with client authentication).

Comment: There's no concern for eavesdropping. But digital signature is needed to confirm that public key is in fact correct. And to not have a replay attack, nonce is used.